# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘UniFrac’ for signature ‘"phylo"’

Tags: r, ape-phylo

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ape)
library(phyloseq)

unifrac_unweighted <- UniFrac(tree, weighted = F)

Fehler in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘UniFrac’ for signature ‘"phylo"’
3.
stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
2.
(function (classes, fdef, mtable) { methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable) if (length(methods) == 1L) ...
1.
UniFrac(tree_BLS, weighted = T)
```

tree is a phylogenetic tree (proved with `class(tree)` ). 
I already tried to reinstall phyloseq but it does not help. How to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UniFrac` function requirs a `phyloseq` object:

```
physeq: (Required). ‘phyloseq-class’, containing at minimum a
          phylogenetic tree (‘phylo-class’) and contingency table
          (‘otu_table-class’). See examples below for coercions that
          might be necessary
```

Not very sure if it makes sense for you, but maybe consider the below example. The key is to construct the phyloseq object correctly, one part I am not sure of is how to construct the otu_table, I set `taxa_are_row=FALSE` :

```
#you get a tree
sample_tree = rtree(20,tip.label=letters[1:20])

# there are counts associated with each sample in tree
sample_counts = matrix(rnbinom(100*20,mu=20,size=1),
ncol=20,dimnames=list(1:100,letters[1:20]))

x1 = phyloseq(
otu_table(sample_counts,taxa_are_row=FALSE), 
sample_tree)

UniFrac(x1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try running a line like:

```
phyloseq_object@phy_tree <- NULL
```

Remember if you re-run this code it flips it. So maybe you loaded in your environment and ran some code/touched up some older lines... or maybe you never started with it. Possibly the reverse of the code i gave is needed is the tree is supposed to be present.